# Who pays for national political conventions?

Tags: united-states, parties, republican-party, democratic-party

> "There is certainly no money available from us for hosting this event," Cooper told reporters Thursday. (referring to hosting the RNC nominating convention)

Nashville TN, Mayor Cooper said several days ago. [Tennessean](https://www.tennessean.com/story/news/politics/2020/06/04/nashville-has-no-money-host-republican-convention-mayor-cooper/3144136001/)

Presumably, Mayor Cooper is referring to non-reimbursable expenses that would be the sole responsibility of the City.

As I "think" I understand it, Congress ended the practice of providing grants for expenses (including security?) in 2014 and replaced that with the ability of convention committees to seek donors to fund the conventions. However that donation amount is limited to about 100,000 dollars per donor. [Open Secrets](https://www.opensecrets.org/pres16/conventions)
That would seem to suggest that the city of Nashville could only "donate" 100,000 to a national political convention. Is that accurate?

How are national political conventions funded?
Although there may have been changes in laws and regulations since 2016, it might be instructive to see a city's balance sheet for hosting a political convention in 2016.